# How to solve "signatures couldn't be verified" when running "sudo apt-get update"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, aptitude

Hi i got this error while running the sudo apt-get update
command on my Ubuntu machine :(

**Error:**

```
Fetched 308B in 1s (158B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net intrepid Release: 
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key
  is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A9BF3BB4E5E17B5
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Comment: This really does belong on superuser, even though you are getting stuck after adding a launchpad PPA.

Comment: yes. how can i solve this. ?

Comment: Wait for it to be migrated to superuser and you'll get plenty of help.

Comment: Given ~unutbu's answer I doubt it will help, but: did you try *to run apt-get update to correct these problems*?

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the gpg key:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 4E5E17B5
gpg --export --armor 4E5E17B5 | sudo apt-key add -
```

See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=6626085#post6626085

Comment: ===gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error=====

getting error :(

Comment: The keyserver might be down. You may have to wait and try again later.
See also http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1221323 for `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 5A9BF3BB4E5E17B5` which should also fix the problem once the keyserver is working.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 9.10, if repositories are added using the command add-apt-repository, the keys are automatically imported. This way, you don't get this error/warning.